# Getting batch job id nside ItemProcessListener in spring batch 5

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My listener is as given below :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ProcessorExecutionListener implements ItemProcessListener<OriginDAO, DestinationDAO> {


    @Override
    public void onProcessError(OriginDAO originADAO, Exception e) {
        log.error("Want to display batch job id here in the logs. Is it possible?");
    }

}
```

I want to display batch job id in my logs on err. Any idea? ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by making the listener step-scoped and inject the step execution in it. Here is an example:

```
@Component
@StepScope
@Slf4j
public class ProcessorExecutionListener implements ItemProcessListener< OriginDAO, DestinationDAO> {

    @Value("#{stepExecution}")
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(OriginDAO item, Exception e) {
        Long jobId = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobId();
        log.error("batch job id = {}", jobId);
    }
    
}
```

This listener should be registered in the step as a listener as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahmoud as usual you are the best :)

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it helped and thank you for the kind words!

Comment: However i am getting this err:, anything missing: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.jobCompletionNotificationListener': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton

Comment: Please edit the question with all the code and the complete stack trace and I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It was my bad i was trying this on JobExecutionListener rather than on ItemProcessListener, it is all good.